# App Ionic+Laravel on my smartphone, Can i run it locally?

Tags: laravel, testing, ionic-framework, localhost, laravel-8

I created an application using ionic for the front-end and laravel for the back-end, I wanted to test the app on my smartphone without buying hosts, etc ...

I created the apk (using ionic cap build android), I installed it on the device and obviously the calls to the database do not work ...

searching on the internet I tried to replace localhost:8000 with my-ip-address:8000 but:

- nothing, although if I search from the browser of my smartphone I enter the default view of the laravel project.
- now if I try to start the livereload (ionic serve) on my pc, it gives me error: Failed to load resource: net :: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED.

Is it possible to test my application on my smartphone by running Laravel locally?

Answer (score 0):

You can give your API an external URL using a tool like NGROK or Local tunnel which will give you a public URL for your local API.

https://ngrok.com/

https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel